# Difference between accepter and acceptor

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

What is the difference between these two words:

- accepter
- acceptor

On Merriam-Webster, each word's definitions are linked to one another,

> #### [Definition of accepter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accepter)
>
> 1. one that accepts
> 2. [acceptor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acceptor)

---

> #### [Definition of acceptor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acceptor)
>
> 1. [accepter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accepter)
> 2. one that accepts an order or a bill of exchange
> 3. an atom, molecule, or subatomic particle capable of receiving another entity (as an electron) especially to form a compound — compare donor

Do both words mean the exact same thing or are each used differently depending on the context they are in?

Comment: They seem like regional synonyms to me.

Comment: There is an old "guideline" that's been used in the computer industry for at least 50 years that the "-er" words are for human actors and the "-or" words are for mechanisms.  But I have no idea whether this is backed by any "ivory castle" academics or is just something produced by the chief documentation folks in IBM.

Comment: @HotLicks That would explain why "acceptor" has the third definition

Comment: @HotLicks And yet, we don't have acters.

Comment: @Tom, that's because actors are secretly mechanical...

Comment: @JohnClifford ...or docters. BTW, if singers sing, and workers work, do doctors doct?

Comment: @Tom - Specifically, it explains why the thing attached to an old IBM 360 "channel" was a "selector".  And, in my experience, it's been a useful guideline in other cases where there is some ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

I just think that ***acceptor*** is an older form of ***accepter***. Though there are roughly parallel entries for them in the OED. ***Acceptor*** is certainly still in current use, but modern people I suggest would be inclined to use the ***accepter*** spelling.

So far as such instruments as Bills of Exchange are concerned, both are in use.

> 2004   Racing Post 7 May 8/2   A full list of acceptors will be issued
>   tomorrow after the extended deadline, but one name confirmed yesterday
>   was the Godolphin filly Punctilious.

Comment: Collins says [acceptor](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/acceptor) is more common than accepter; -or is in the top 30,000 words but -er is not.